# How can i run my android program in LG android mobile version 4.0?

Tags: android

I am using linux os and running a android program in my mobile .
my mobile version is 4.0 but my mobile is not detecting for checking the android output .
i can do data transfer but the android program is not running in my device.

Comment: Could you please explain what you are doing? "it was not detected". What process did not detect what thing? Explain what you did, in what environment, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to system settings ----> Select USB debugging options.

It is very important to use the same USB for the same mobile.Its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

For New Android Devices, you need to download the Device Drivers from LG website or if you are familiar with android sdk then that comes with variety of the android device drivers.

Once the phone is getting detected by computer you need to install ADB interface for your device, which is actually used to install the applications.

Comment: No.your prediction is wrong.I got the answer for question

Comment: That's right you need to download drivers, for SAMSUNG it won't work unless you download kies, and on SONY you need drivers, so LG devices should be the same

Comment: @Deepak : Please mark the correct answer as accepted so we will come to know what is the solution you got.

Comment: i am using ADT tool for running my application it does not need any drivers and KIES.I got the answer.Thanks for trying.

Comment: @  Dinesh Prajapati i have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> If you are developing on Windows and would like to connect an
>   Android-powered device to test your applications, then you need to
>   install the appropriate USB driver.

Check [**OEM USB Drivers**](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) page and read all the instructions and download suitable driver.

After installing USB Driver, you need to enable USB Debugging in your device. Read instruction for [**Using Hardware devices**](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your manifest file?

Maybe you need to declare min and max SDK used.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

SDK 14 is for android 4.0, but I don't see why shouldnt you put the latest SDK, like this

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```